# Conditional json parsing in Scala

Tags: json, scala, jackson

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class CampaignSparkParameters( category : String )
                                    object CampaignSparkParameters  {
                                    case class Inner(  
                                    booster: String,
                                    tree_method: String,
                                     verbosity:Int,
                                     nthread:String,
                                     num_workers:Int,
                                     early_stopping_rounds:Int,
                                     colsample_bytree:Float,
                                     subsample:Float,
                                     objective:String,
                                     eval_metric:String,
                                     lambda : Float,
                                     eta:Float,
                                     alpha:Float,
                                     gamma:Float,
                                     max_depth:Int,
                                     max_bin:Int,
                                     num_round:Int,
                                     missing:Int,
                                     seed:String ) 
                                    }

object CampaignSparkParameterParser {

  val mapper: ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper = (new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper)
    .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
    .asInstanceOf[ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper]

  def parseParameters(args: Array[String]): CampaignSparkParameters = {
    mapper.readValue[CampaignSparkParameters](args(0))
  }

  def parametersToArgs(parameters: CampaignSparkParameters): Array[String] = {
    Array(
      mapper
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(parameters)
    )
  }
  def sparkParamsToMap(parameters: CampaignSparkParameters): Map[String, Any] = {
    Map(
    )
  }
}
```

I am passing an input of a json like this

**Input json**
val prparamas= CampaignSparkParameters(
 [{"category":"x","data":{"booster":"gbtree","tree_method":"hist","verbosity":"1","nthread":"cpuTask","num_workers":"35","early_stopping_rounds":"5","colsample_bytree":"0.9","subsample":"0.9","objective":"binary_logistic","eval_metric":"logloss","lambda":"10.0","eta":"0.1","alpha":"1.0","gamma":"0.0","max_depth":"5","max_bin":"64","num_round":"100","missing":"0","seed":"42L"}},
{"category":"y","data":{"booster":"gbtree","tree_method":"hist","verbosity":"1","nthread":"cpuTask","num_workers":"35","early_stopping_rounds":"5","colsample_bytree":"0.9","subsample":"0.9","objective":"binary_logistic","eval_metric":"logloss","lambda":"10.0","eta":"0.1","alpha":"1.0","gamma":"0.0","max_depth":"5","max_bin":"64","num_round":"100","missing":"0","seed":"42L"}}
]
)

**Call to function**
val prparamas1 = prparamas.sparkParamsToMap(prparamas)

**output expected**

if category  = x then that data should be mapped and displayed. please help me to modify the above code.

Currently I am getting error

:5: error: illegal character '\u00a0'
val prparamas= CampaignSparkParameters(

Answer (score 0):

`\u00a0` is a non-breaking space character, so you probably have some of these in your string that you can't see. A simple replace might fix it:

```
json.replaceAll("\u00a0", " ")
```

Or simply delete each character in the input that looks like a space and replace with a normal space.

Comment: It did not work. I tried this. Also, I wanted to know how to add case statement to sparkParamsToMap function.